# Missing Ivy Resolve Visualizer

Tags: eclipse, ivy

In eclipse neon, I am trying to access the Ivy Resolve Visualizer view from the Show View. I can only see Ivy Report & Reserve Dependency Explorer. Not sure what is missing. I uninstall IvyDE and re-installed it, but still the same problem. Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install the visualizer plugin separately within Eclipse, selecting the Apache Ivy update site as the source.  It does not seem to included in the standard IvyDE plugin installation.